# How to stop images stretching in Safari when using flex css

Tags: html, css

2 img elements inside a div. I want the images displayed next to each other rather than stacked, so applied flex. I also want both images to be equal in width and height.

It works perfectly on every browser (chrome, opera, firefox, brave) apart from safari. I've read safari is bugged so stretches the images.

I added align-items: flex-start; which fixes the stretching, but then the height of the 2 images becomes uneven at the bottom.

[image]

I've just set a webkit css for now, so height is uneven only on safari and fine on other browsers.

Is there any way around this?

CSS:

```css
.portfolio-box {
    margin-top: 40px;
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
}

.portfolio-box > * + * {
    margin-left: 4%;
}

.portfolio-box img {
    width: 48%;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 150px;
}
```

HTML:

```html
<div class="portfolio-box">
     <img src="./img/portfolio2.jpg" alt="">
     <img src="./img/portfolio3.jpg" alt="">
</div>
```

Comment: Could you clarify what you want the outcome to be? The images displayed at equal widths and however tall they are? Or equal widths and heights? What do you expect to happen with the extra whitespace below the shorter image? Could  you also provide some details as to what Safari version you're using? (I plopped the code you have above into CodePen and I see the same across Chrome, FF and Safari.)

Comment: Hey, just edited the op to clarify. I want to display both images at equal width and height, the css above works perfectly for all browsers but safari stretches it. If I add align-items: flex-start; then it fixes the stretch on safari, but then height becomes uneven at bottom on all browsers. Hope that's clearer.

Answer (score 2):

The images (vertically, I'm assuming) stretching is default flexbox behavior, not a Safari bug. I grabbed [your code snippets and put them into Codepen](https://codepen.io/code-and-pixels/pen/qBqyrgR) - they look the same across Safari (Mac) and Firefox/Chrome (Win10).

I added a few other variations of your code below the 1st bit, but the very last bit I also limited the height of the images. You can see they become distorted again.

You could possibly use "object-fit" on the images like so (or see bottom example in the above linked Codepen):

```css
img {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
}
```

However, you can see that the 1st image (the taller one) is cropped.

At the end of the day, if you want the height and width of images to match in a flexbox layout without distortion or cropping, they need to have matching dimensions to begin with.

Comment: Only mentioned the safari bug because the original css seems to work perfectly on all browsers, apart from safari - they all display equal width and height with no distortion.

I did try the object-fit rule, but the crop wasn't great. I think you're right, best solution is probably just to adjust the img sizes in photoshop to equal dimensions. Was just curious to see a css workaround for safari.

Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, wish there had been an easier answer. Good luck out there!

Comment: Thanks! i was missing the object-fit: cover; That along with width: 100%; fixed the slight distortion on my images in Safari

Answer (score 0):

I think that JavaScript may help you. If the only thing that you are missing on is the uneven height of elements on Safari Browser, then you can set equal height of the elements using a simple JavaScript function. This will work on every browser and you won't need to prefix your CSS.

```js
function setEqualHeight() {
    'use strict';
    
    var firstElement        = document.getElementById("first-element");
    var firstElementHeight  = document.getElementById("first-element").clientHeight;

    var secondElement       = document.getElementById("second-element");
    var secondElementHeight = document.getElementById("second-element").clientHeight;

    if (firstElementHeight > secondElementHeight) {
        secondElement.style.height = firstElementHeight + "px";
    } else {
        firstElement.style.height = secondElementHeight + "px";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I may test this out.